# Implement a special alloc and free methods with data structures as part of the working memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

You're given a section of memory, say 1MB, and a pointer to the start of this memory `P`

You need to implement `void * alloc()` and `void free(void* p)`

`Alloc` is allocating a block of memory which is 16B and returns a pointer to the start of it

`Free` receives a pointer to a start of a block and frees its memory, notice it can be anywhere in the given block

You can assume calling these methods will always be when there is space to `alloc` and the same for `free`, it will always be in the block, so there is no need to handle out of bounds such edge cases

[image]

The catch is that alloc and free data structures should be part of the given block.

The solution I tried is to use a bitmap such that each bit will point to a specific block, this will take 2^13B space because 2^20B/2^4B/2^3B=(total/block size/amount of bits in each byte)=8192 which is almost 1% of 2^20.

Also, this means that the runtimes for `alloc` will be O(n) to find a 0 bit and `free` will be O(1).

The question is, how can this be implemented with O(1) runtime for both `alloc` and `free` and to have 0% used memory?

Note this is an exercise, it's not language or OS specific.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve `O(1) runtime` for `alloc` and `free` with 0% wasted memory, use a `segregated free list` approach. Divide the `memory block` into `fixed-size blocks &  each block is either allocated or part of a free list.

**Setup:**

Start with a 1MB memory block.
`Initialize` a `"free list header"` to manage free blocks, containing `pointers` to `free lists` for different block sizes.

**`alloc` Function:**

Find the appropriate `free list` based on `block size.`
If a free block exists, allocate it; else, split a larger block, add to smaller list, and return the other.Access and update linked lists for free lists in constant time.

**`free` Function:**

Calculate the block's free list based on size.
Add the block to the corresponding `free list, O(1)` operation.
Minimal memory overhead, as free list headers and pointers are efficient. Achieve O(1) runtime for both functions and no memory wastage

Comment: can you explain how you maintain this free list and how much memory it takes?